# Java return JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to create a jsonarray from a Map in java.  I'm passing it in to a javascript variable.  But i don't know why the mac and status are blank, any help much appreciated.

what i need:

```
[{"12345":{"mac":"FFFFFFFF", "status":"ON"}]
```

What i am getting with my current code:

```
[{"12345":{}]
```

Here is my code,

```
public class Details {

public JSONArray getResult() {
    return JSONArray.fromObject(this.det);
}
public Map det = new HashMap();

public results() {
   ResultSet rs;
   det.put(rs.getString(1), new NodeDetails(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
}
class NodeDetails {
    public final String MAC;
    public final String status;

    public NodeDetails(final String ma,final String st) {
        this.MAC = ma;
        this.status = st;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any limitation on any library? I mean are you using JSON library from http://org.json or which library?

Following is the code that I've tried using JSON library from http://org.json:

```
public class Test {

    public static class NodeDetails {
        public final String MAC;
        public final String status;

        public NodeDetails(final String ma, final String st) {
            this.MAC = ma;
            this.status = st;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, NodeDetails> map = new HashMap<String, NodeDetails>();
        // do something with you ResultSet? and populate the map ;)
        map.put("12345", new NodeDetails("FFFFFF", "ON"));

        JSONObject jsonMap = new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, NodeDetails> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put(entry.getValue().MAC, entry.getValue().status);
            jsonMap.put(entry.getKey(), object);
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(jsonMap);

        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());

    }
}
```

You can read more about the API here:
http://json.org/java/

Answer (score 0):

[JsonArray.fromObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#fromObject%28java.lang.Object%29)-- Creates a JSONArray.
Inspects the object type to call the correct JSONArray factory method. **Accepts JSON formatted strings, arrays and Collections**.

And Map which you are passing is not JSON formatted. So try using add() method on JsonArray Or put() method on JsonObject.